# Variadic template error -- MSVS2013 compiles, clang-3.5 does not

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, clang++

The code below compiles and runs fine with MSVC 2013, but not clang++3.6.
**Which compiler is correct?**

MSVC 2013 compiles and executes the code, printing **26.04**:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename ... U>
auto mul(T t, U ... u) -> decltype(t * mul(u ...))
{
    return t * mul(u ...);
}

template <typename T>
T mul(T t) { return t; }

int main()
{
    std::cout << mul(2., 3.1, 4.2) << std::endl;
}
```

However, compiling with clang++-3.6 yields errors:

```
$ clang++ test.cpp -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 
prog.cc:14:15: error: no matching function for call to 'mul'
        std::cout << mul(2., 3.1, 4.2) << std::endl;
                     ^~~
prog.cc:4:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = double, U = <double, double>]: use of undeclared identifier 'mul'
auto mul(T t, U ... u) -> decltype(t * mul(u ...))
     ^                                 ~~~
prog.cc:10:3: note: candidate function template not viable: requires single argument 't', but 3 arguments were provided
T mul(T t) { return t; }
  ^
1 error generated.
```

Is the declaration of mul is not available to determine the return typedecl?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to define the return type of `mul` in terms of the return type of `mul`. More precisely, you are using `mul` in the `decltype` expression, before it is fully declared (which is exactly, what the compiler error is telling you).
MSVC's template instantiate works in a non-standard-conforming way, which is why I believe that clang is correct - it could, however, be implementation defined but I don't think so (maybe someone knows the relevant part of the standard).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you replace your call in `main` with `mul(2., 3.1)` (two arguments), you code still won't compile in Clang and GCC. But in this case it will not compile simply because your single-argument `mul` is declared *after* the multiple-argument version. The single-argument version is not yet known at the point of declaration of multiple-argument version. If you move the single-argument declaration to the top, the `mul(2., 3.1)` call will compile. It compiles because the return type specification `decltype(t * mul(u ...))` refers to an already fully-declared single-argument version of `mul`.

Secondly, the original call with three arguments `mul(2., 3.1, 4.2)` does not compile because it attempts to recursively declare its return type through itself (through a two-argument version, which still refers to the same template). This is not allowed. Yes, we all know that the recursion is well-defined and bottoms out eventually, but the language does not allow that. (Still looking for the formal quote...)